# Python Manually creating a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

how to do this so its more readable in code:   the list should look some thing like this [["a","b"],["c","d","e"]]

```
foo = []   #create empty list
foo[0] = [] #create empty list for index 0
foo[1]=[] #create empty list to index of 1
foo[0][0] = "a" #assign a to index of 0,0 as per above example.
foo[0][1] = "b" #assign b to index of 0,1 as per above example.
foo[1][0] = "c" # and so on......
```

I have this working with a for loop like the code below. But I have longer strings in my code and lots of nested lists like above example, so primary index is going up to 10 or some thing e.g list[10][8]. This is making code look almost unreadable.

Some thing like above would be cool so its easier to sort and redefine things or variables as necessary...

Also, can a items inside a list or nested list be variables? So I can just change the strings in variable names and it updates my code without retyping things again?

```
list=[]
list.append(["a","b"])
list.append(["c","d","e"])
print(list)
for i in list:
    for n in i:
        test = "it works"
        results= test + " "+ n
        print(results)

[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
it works a
it works b
it works c
it works d
it works e
```

**UPDATES**

I am trying to create automated folders on my system so certain folders are same under a project e.g Project1>In,out,work>[coding, graphics, animation etc.] Project2 will have similar directory structure inside it.... now my code looks too long like i said i have got it working but is there a way in to add things manually like in the foo example? its just more redable that way and easy to edit if i come back to it few months down the lane.

my current nested array looks like this

```
(["\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Comp",
  "\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\FX",
  "\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Lighting",
  "\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Animation",
  "\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Modeling",
  "\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Plates",
  "\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Camera",
  "\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Concept"])
```

Comment: `lst = [["a","b"],["c","d","e"]]`. it's best practice not to use `list` as a variable name, as you shadow the builtin list.

Comment: What is the overall goal of this script? If you are just looking for `[["a","b"],["c","d","e"]]`, then `list=[];list.append(["a","b"]);list.append(["c","d","e"])` is fine. However, what would be your desired output for your longer and more generic input?

Comment: @Ajax1234 I am trying to create automated folders on my system so certain folders are same under a project e.g Project1>In,out,work>[coding, graphics, animation etc.] Project2 will have similar directory structure inside it.... now my code looks too long like i said i have got it working but is there a way in to add things manually like in the foo example? its just more redable that way and easy to edit if i come back to it few months down the lane.

Comment: @Ajax1234   my current nested array looks like this (["\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Comp","\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\FX","\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Lighting","\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Animation","\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Modeling","\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Plates","\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Camera","\\shots\\"+_SC+"\\Concept"])

Comment: Please add these question clarifications into the question body itself, not in the comments.

Comment: @Prune i tried to edit>copy paste clarifications in question body but for some reson it wont paste sorry very new here...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your variable `_SC` might be, but making a short, readable initialization for this is pretty straightforward.  Put the common prefix into a variable; put the changing parts into a list.  Then use a list comprehension to prepend the prefix to each choice in turn, making a list out of the result.

```
category = [
    "Comp",
    "FX",
    "Lighting"
    "Animation",
    "Modeling",
    "Plates",
    "Camera",
    "Concept"
]

"prefix = \\shots\\" + _SC + "\\"
catalog = [prefix + area for area in category]
```